# gulp doesn't watch my subdirectories

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-watch

I'm trying to set up gulp to watch all my sass files, but I'm having trouble with my subdirectories.

This is my file structure in the scss folder:
default.scss
-base
-components

My gulpfile is set up like this:

```
const SCSS_SRC  = './src/assets/scss/**/*.scss';
const SCSS_DEST = './src/assets/css';

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src(SCSS_SRC)
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(changed(SCSS_DEST))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(SCSS_DEST))
});

gulp.task('default', function () {
    gulp.watch(SCSS_SRC, ['sass']);
});
```

When I run gulp the first time, everything is compiled normally, but if i make changes in my sass files in the subdirectories they are not compiled.
If I make a change in the default style, the files in the subdirectories are compiled too though. But I don't want to have to update the default file everytime I update the other files.

This is the first time I use gulp, so I'm sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: I would remove the changed pipe to see if it helps - it is not doing much if anything there anyhow.

Comment: Thank you @Mark , that solved it immediately!

Comment: I'll make it an answer - that is a non-standard usage/placement of gulp-changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest simply removing the pipe(changed()) call as changed to usually used to filter the stream immediately after gulp.src.  Unless you have a huge project I just don't see that it could be very useful right before gulp.dest.  It is an easy thing to try to see if it helps.